How to make certain bones not affect entire meshes
I am currently rigging a character for the first time but I am having issues rigging it in the way i want.
I created a very simple character with 2 arm, 2 leg, 3 body and 1 head bone. However when i rig the armature to my entire character i run into issue. For example i want the arm to not affect the entire face mesh when moving. I achieved this by creating a seperate bone rig for the arms only but i run into the issue of the arms not following the body bones when rotating the body. Also for example when I try to make my character look up at the sky, all of the face features get distorted when in reality I want the face and face features to move as if you rotated them in object mode. What am i doing wrong?

You need to weight paint your model. Here is a good tutorial for it. But basically what is happening, is the arm bone (for example) has control of your face mesh. You need to remove the weight from the places it doesnt belong. Adding automatic weights is good for a first pass, but you want to tweak it to make it work properly.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xooago2F8h8&list=PLcaQc6eQjXCxWXmn5jxE_GTOft9ZxChu1&index=10

hello maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

I think the issue is, that you need a root bone. You can rig your character probably with one armature. Then you create a root bone, and assign it any geometry that is not affected by any other bones. Think of it as the catch-all category. Except it doesnt contain the stuff that is actually rigged, like the arm.
Hope that helps!
